# distinguish if function argument optional

Tags: typescript

How to distinguish if function argument optional?

How to distinguish

```
(p?: string): object
```

and

```
(p: string): object
```

I tried this

```
type A = {
  (p?: string): object
}
type B<A> = A extends (p: string | undefined) => object ? string : number
type C = B<A>
```

but it doesn't work

Is there some way to  distinguish them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a conditional type to test if your function is assignable to another that has an optional first argument. So something like:

```
type A = {
  (p?: string): object
}

type B = {
    (p: string): object
}

type OptionalFirstArg = (a?: never) => unknown;

type IsOpt<F> = F extends OptionalFirstArg ? true : false;

type testA = IsOpt<A>; // testA is true
type testB = IsOpt<B>; // testB is false
```

Here's a [playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oAowH4BcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYCUBA9gEYBWEAxsCgL4oqiRQAQgmRoM2AsXLU6UJqw7de-aAHkwwMvQoBDADYAxMiWIwSVEZh34oFCADcIJGggB8UAK4UA1hXoB3CgBuZXBoAElCdWAAHgN3RAMoCAAPYAgKABNCKGitXUNjU3MoHChSD2gCADN9QggQvjDyiFMRSOiYmFcgqAB6Ppa2shyKiCaBdOJhRA6NGMEe-sGp4GERqFq9eqA) for the above code.

Comment: It's a great way to solve this problem. But when I do some thing like this with VS Code. Both value will be the `true`. The version I used is 3.6.2.

Comment: @MaTianqi This approach requires the `strictNullChecks` compiler option to be on.

Answer (score 1):

You can make distinction by checking against `() => object` when parameter is not present.

```js
type A1 = {
  (p?: string): object; // optional input parameter
}
type A2 = {
  (p: string): object; // required input parameter
}
type B<T extends (p: string) => object> =
  T extends () => object ?
    number
    : T extends (p: string) => object
    ? string
    : never;

type C1 = B<A1>; // number
type C2 = B<A2>; // string
```